# How to iterate ARRAY of ARRAY in PostgreSQL to insert values in to another table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm trying to define some csv rows as in the below code, and iterate them so that I can insert those into a new table. But while executing this it complains with the below error:

`SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: FOREACH loop variable must not be of an array type`.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    contact_mapping TEXT[][] := ARRAY[
        ARRAY['1', '1', '1', '1', 'false', 'true', 'email1@abc.com'],
        ARRAY['2', '1', '1', '1', 'true', 'false', 'email2@abc.com'],
        ARRAY['3', '1', '1', NULL, 'false', 'true', 'email3@abc.com']
    ];
    row_data text[];
BEGIN
    FOREACH row_data IN ARRAY contact_mapping
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO contact_notification (
            article_id,
            contact_id,
            is_free,
            is_public
        )
        SELECT
            ca.article_id,
            ec.contact_id,
            (row_data[5] = 'true')::BOOLEAN,
            (row_data[6] = 'true')::BOOLEAN
        FROM article ca
        CROSS JOIN contact ec
        WHERE (ec.email = row_data[7])
        AND (row_data[1] IS NULL OR ca.cl_one = row_data[1])
        AND (row_data[2] IS NULL OR ca.cl_two = row_data[2])
        AND (row_data[3] IS NULL OR ca.cl_three = row_data[3])
        AND (row_data[4] IS NULL OR ca.cl_four = row_data[4]);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```

Comment: An array is not appropriate here (unless there is some external constraint forcing you to use one, in which case you should share it). Neither is a `FOREACH` loop. SQL is a language design to process data, very much including inserting it, in bulk. Also, do an `INNER JOIN` rather than a `CROSS JOIN` followed by a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So... from your comment, I conclude you have no external constraint. A simple `WITH contact([...]) AS (VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 'false', 'true', 'email1@abc.com'), [...]) INSERT INTO [...] SELECT [...] from article ca INNER JOIN contact ON [...]` will do the trick.